# Issue with packages permissions

Tags: centos, permissions, rpm

I have an issue with some ownership and permissions unintentionally changed on files in **/usr/bin** and I want to know if there is a way to recover the default ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recover  packages default permissions and ownership.

Make a loop over the above command to get the package name of each provided file under /usr/bin
:

`yum whatprovides /usr/bin`

And then loop again on the above commands by replacing the packages by those get from the last command :

`rpm --setugids <package>`
`rpm --setperms <package>`

This must be in the correct order.